# Get current array value of a Mongo Array in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

What I want is to get the current array listing from an "#each" command, so for the first one it returns 0, the following 1, and so on.

I can get the current values within it such as {{this.valueName}}, but how do I get the numerical place in the array?

Edit - Code for context:

```
{{#each entry}}
{{> childtemplate}}
{{/each}}

<template name="childtemplate">
    <p class="list-group-item-heading">
      {{@index}}<br>
      Name: {{this.name}}
    </p>
</template>
```

Using @index gives me this:

> Error: Unsupported directive: @index meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `{{@index}}`. You also don't need `this`, `{{valueName}}` is sufficient.

Comment: Ok, that works but it it doesn't extend down to child templates throws errors with the @index.

I was using the "this.valueName" to keep some odd behavior from cropping up.

Comment: You'd have to show your code for us to assess why you're getting such errors. Build an understanding of data contexts.

Comment: Ok, got it, I had send the context over like this: {{> childtemplate entry=this index=@index}}, and the child template just needed to look at rule.value.  Hopefully this wont make any further issues, but for now everything is working as advertised.